# table inside a div without alternating row color using BluePrint CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors, blueprint-css

The Blueprint CSS Framework 1.0.1 set all table rows of alternating colors by default. The line in screen.css is:

```
tbody tr:nth-child(even) td, tbody tr.even td {background:#e5ecf9;}
```

that's fine

but i need to disable this behaviour for one table inside a div (inside) a modal windows using the simplemodal jquery plugin by eric martin, i just tried to override the css using:

```
#contact-container tbody tr:nth-child(even) td, tbody tr.even td {background:#FFFFCC;}
```

in other css file name custom.css loaded after screen.css but this override affect all tables in page even outside contact-container

is there any way to override the behaviour just for that table inside div ?

Anyone can help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to use !important Declaration and see what happens!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the id in one place:

```
#contact-container tbody tr:nth-child(even) td, 
tbody tr.even td 
{
    background:#FFFFCC;
}
```

This is really equivalent to this:

```
#contact-container tbody tr:nth-child(even) td
{
    background:#FFFFCC;
}

tbody tr.even td 
{
    background:#FFFFCC;
}
```

If formatted as above, you can see the issue.  The 2nd half of that is not specific to your id.  Change it to this:

```
#contact-container tbody tr:nth-child(even) td, 
#contact-container tbody tr.even td 
{
    background:#FFFFCC;
}
```

Comment: excellent James, it's works, THANK YOU SOME MUCH, now i'm going to analize the solution, best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can forbid overwritting with `!important`:

```
#contact-container tr {background:#FFFFCC !important;}
```

Comment: i just tried, but the final results inside the div contact-container is as the original blueprint styles applied:

tbody tr:nth-child(even) td, tbody tr.even td {background:#e5ecf9;}

Comment: You have to overwrite each rule with a more *important* rule.